# Anywhere in Tanach where brothers-in-law have the same name?

Tags: names, tanach, family-members, historical-figures

Is there anywhere in Tanach where brothers-in-law have the same name?

Either two sisters married men with the same name, or a woman married someone with the same name as her brother.

There is a situation like this in my family and I am looking for parallels in Tanach.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a riddle. See [this meta post](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/140/759). Try including some motivation behind the question to make it a better fit for Mi Yodeya.

Comment: @DoubleAA Is curiosity a good enough motive?

Comment: @DoubleAA Huh? By that logic, every question is a riddle.

Comment: @DoubleAA There is a situation like this in my family and I am looking for parallels in Tanach, that is my motivation. But that shouldn't matter - it doesn't really add to the question.

Comment: @DoubleAA I can reasonably classify this question as a riddle too: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/19111/source-of-non-verse-in-selichot

Comment: @Imray, your motivation definitely adds something to the question. First of all, in clarifying that this is *not* a riddle, you've made it clear that you don't know that such a situation exists. (Your question would be clear enough on this point, except that the type of question it is made it *look like* a "I know the answer - do you?" riddle.) Also, if people know what you want this information for, it makes it easier for them to determine what kinds of detail to include in their answers and which edge cases may be close enough to be useful. I suggest adding even more on why you want this.

Comment: ... @DoubleAA's initial misinterpretation of this question was understandable, given its formal similarity to such actual riddle questions as http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5320/ and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3935/ . Note the major problematic characteristic of these questions: The only [possible] motivation for the question is that the asker knows the answer and is challenging others to discover it, which necessitates hiding information in the question. See [the post](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/140/759) DoubleAA linked.

Comment: Riddle != question. Read the post I linked to.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I think it's pretty unlikely that I spent time to type up a riddle, to challenge everyone's knowledge for my personal amusement. What would be the point? If I did do that, why would I not tag it as such? And even if I do provide motivation, how do you know I didn't fabricate it in pursuit of my deranged pleasure of wasting people's time on a question I already know the answer to?

Comment: @Imray, I won't defend the practice, but there's ample history of people posting [tag:riddle]s just as you describe, with or without initially including that tag. | We don't care about the intention in your head; we care about the point-of-view expressed in the question. The question needs to make the case for its own relevance and include as much information as possible that would help answerers make their answers relevant and focused. There's interesting discussion related to this, on a network-wide scale, [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164436/179).